# Trying to combine the randomize numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to pass them in a function and put into the array but the results. I cannot think of any solutions. this is the result:

the one I want is look like this

```
[4,4,5,4]
```

but the output is

```
[4, 4, 4, 4]
[4, 4, 4, 4]
[5, 5, 5, 5]
[4, 4, 4, 4]






  $("#machine1").slotMachine({
     active : 0,
     delay : 500,
     randomize : function(activeElementIndex){
     var activeElementIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
     //console.log(activeElementIndex);
     call_me(activeElementIndex);
     return activeElementIndex;
    }
    }).shuffle(5);  

    $("#machine2").slotMachine({
     active : 0,
     delay : 700,
     direction: 'down',
     randomize : function(activeElementIndex){
     var activeElementIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
     //console.log(activeElementIndex);
     call_me(activeElementIndex);
     return activeElementIndex;
    }
    }).shuffle(5);

    $("#machine3").slotMachine({
     active : 0,
     delay : 900,
     randomize : function(activeElementIndex){
     var activeElementIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
     //console.log(activeElementIndex);
     call_me(activeElementIndex);
     return activeElementIndex;
    }
    }).shuffle(5);

    $("#machine4").slotMachine({
     active : 0,
     delay : 1100,
     direction: 'down',
     randomize : function(activeElementIndex){
     var activeElementIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
     //console.log(activeElementIndex);
     call_me(activeElementIndex);
     return activeElementIndex;
    }
    }).shuffle(5);

    function call_me(wait){
     var nice = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
     nice[i] = wait;
     }
     console.log(nice);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the `nice[]` array outside any function and switch:

```
call_me(activeElementIndex) > nice.push(activeElementIndex)
```

Comment: Thank you, It fixed my problem! Thumbs up for you!